# Proof for Bases of Eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across a proof that showed that the union of the bases of eigenspaces are linearly independent.

The statement for the proof was: Suppose $V$ is a vector space and the endomorphism $\Phi$ has distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ and each eigenspace has a basis $B_{\lambda_j}$. Prove that $B=B_{\lambda_1}\cup\dots\cup B_{\lambda_n}$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$.

There's just one step in the proof, I don't understand. Why and how did the author set the indices (that are underlined red in the picture)?[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the headline.

Comment: Observe that $u$ lives in both the union as well as $B_{\lambda_{n + 1}},$ so when we apply $\Phi$ to $u,$ we obtain $\lambda_{n + 1} u.$

Answer (score 1):

1) How did the author set the indices:

Because $u\in B_{\lambda_{n+1}}$, then $\Phi(u)=\lambda_{n+1}u$; and because $v_{i,j}\in B_{\lambda_i}$, then $\Phi(v_{i,j})=\lambda_iv_{i,j}$. So, if we have:

$(*)$ $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n_i}c_{i,j}v_{i,j}=u,$

then applying $\Phi$ in (*) we have:

$\Phi\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n_i}c_{i,j}v_{i,j}\right)=\Phi(u),$

but $\Phi$ is linear, so it preserves sums and scalar multiplications:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n_i}c_{i,j}\Phi\left(v_{i,j}\right)=\Phi(u),$

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n_i}c_{i,j}\lambda_iv_{i,j}=\lambda_{n+1}u.$

$(**)$ $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n_i}\lambda_ic_{i,j}v_{i,j}=\lambda_{n+1}u.$

2) Why the author did this:

Now muultiply (*) by $\lambda_{n+1}$, and we have:

$(***)$ $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n_i}\lambda_{n+1}c_{i,j}v_{i,j}=\lambda_{n+1}u.$

Now do $(**)-(***)$, and we wil get:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n_i}\left(\lambda_i-\lambda_{n+1}\right)c_{i,j}v_{i,j}=0.$

Then use induction hypothesis (that $B_{\lambda_1}\cup\dots\cup B_{\lambda_n}$ is linearly independent) and the fact that $\lambda_i\neq\lambda_{n+1}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Thank you! ;)))

Comment: You can click on the check mark to accept the answer if it solves your problem.